# Нужна помощь с TelegramBot

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Нужна помощь с телеграм ботом, есть код, который должен из двух условий, введенных пользователем, выбирать одно рандомное и выводить, но при вводе условия, он читает только введенные с символом "/", как это исправить, что бы можно было вводить без этого символа и бот считывал, код снизу:

```
class UserChoice:
uslovie1 = "1"
uslovie2 = "2"

@bot.message_handler(commands=["БотИли"])
def БотИли(message: Message):
  UserChoice.uslovie1 = "1"
  UserChoice.uslovie2 = "2"
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите первое условие:")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, ПервоеУсловие)

def ПервоеУсловие(message: Message):
  UserChoice.uslovie1 = message.text
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите второе условие:")
  bot.register_next_step_handler(message, ВтороеУсловие)

def ВтороеУсловие(message: Message):
  UserChoice.uslovie2 = message.text
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Я думаю - {random.choice([UserChoice.uslovie1, UserChoice.uslovie2])}")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)